# Migrate .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1 and keep referencing EF Core 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a C# application written with .NETCore 2.2 and Postgres and I would like to migrate it to .NET Core 3.1.

The problems is that there are so many breaking changes, especially in Entity Framework that it is not possible to rewrite everything now. At the same time, other developers continue development on .NET Core 2.2 branch and I need to do the migration ASAP to prevent merge conflicts and all related problems.

I would like to have .NET Core 3.1 app with the EF Core 2.0 first and resolved these migrations later on.

1. It is possible to reference EF Core 2.0 from .NET Core 3.1 App?
2. Isn't there some magic compatibility switch in .NET Core like Microsoft from time to time provides?

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to reference EF Core 2.0 from .NET Core 3.1 App?

Yes, totally. Doing the same - and then moving off to Ef 6.4 as it looks as the breaking changes are just not bearable. Spending days trying to get basics working.

> Isn't there some magic compatibility switch in .NET Core like Microsoft from time to time 
>   provides?

No. Breaking change after breaking change, particularly in EfCore 3.1.1 - and the promise to fix the bugs. In .NET 5.0, due - ah - November.